# Getting data between a date range and when one of the range is 0 or null

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a hotel reservation website.

I am trying to get data between date range.

| No | Date | Price | Room Available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-12 | 50 | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-05-13 | 50 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022-05-14 | 50 | 0 |
| 4 | 2022-05-15 | 50 | 3 |

my code is:

```
$arrival = $_POST['arrival'];
$checkout = $_POST['checkout'];

$mydb->setQuery("SELECT * FROM 'allotment' WHERE (('$arrival' = DATE_FORMAT('date','%Y-%m-%d'))) AND ROOMID =".$result->ROOMID);

 $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stats);

if ($rows['avaibility'] === NULL) {
$resNum = "Not Available";
$price="0";
}
elseif ($rows['avaibility'] == 0) {
$resNum = "Not Available";
$price="0";
}
else {
$resNum=$rows['avaibility'];
$price=$rows['price'];
}
```

but if you search for the date `2022-05-12 to 2022-05-15` it still shows
even though the date `2022-05-14` is not available

how so that if searching from `2022-05-12 to 2022-05-15`, it shows `is not available` because the date `2022-05-14 is already 0`

Comment: *but if you search for the date 2022-05-12 to 2022-05-15* Your code checks for single date, not for dates range.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT room_number
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN @date_from AND @date_till
GROUP BY room_number
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT date) = 1 + DATEDIFF(@date_till, @date_from);
```

The query returns the room numbers which are available in specified dates range completely.

If `(room_number, date)` is defined as unique then remove DISTINCT.